# exec() command from web server in php

Tags: php, exec

Is there anyway to use atrm command to remove queue job from PHP web application?
I wrote a shell script to remove the queue job but it doesn't work well.

```
#! /bin/sh

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH

echo atrm 3700 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing:

```
echo exec('export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH ; atrm 3700 2>&1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `atrm 3700 2 > &1` without `echo`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shell_exec` or `exec` PHP function :

```
$output=shell_exec($commandstring);
print_r($output);
```

or

```
 exec($commandstring,$output,$returnval);
 print_r($output);
 print_r($returnval);
```